# How to create hash object from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

we have an Input object in this format

```
 var data = [{
      'name':'ABC',
      'age' : 23
 },{
     'name': 'PQR',
      'age' : 34
  },{
    'name': 'SQR',
    'age' : 33
}]
```

we have to make a value of  name as a "key" which is given below.
I will be very thankful to you.

output data

```
var data = {
   'ABC' :{
      'age' : 23
    },
   'PQR' : {
      'age' : 34
   },
   'SQR' :{
     'age' : 33
   }
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Could you please show your efforts and paste an example of your code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.reduce()` to get the desired hash object:

```js
let data = [
  {'name':'ABC', 'age' : 23},
  {'name': 'PQR', 'age' : 34},
  {'name': 'SQR', 'age' : 33}
];

let result = data.reduce((r, {name, ...rest}) => (r[name] = rest, r) , {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `forEach()` to simplify the code:

```js
let data = [
  {'name':'ABC', 'age' : 23},
  {'name': 'PQR', 'age' : 34},
  {'name': 'SQR', 'age' : 33}
];

let result = {};
data.forEach(({name, ...rest}) => (result[name] = rest));

console.log(result);
```